# Reutrn null fields if no match on join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, null, subquery

I have a complex query which I can't quite get right.

I have a table of `lists` which is the master table for `listItems` and a related `items` table. A `list` contains a group of items, e.g. `listId` 1 has two `item`s IDs 1 and 5. The `listItems` table contains a list of all items in each list. The `items` table contains information about the items.

The 'transactions' table is a list of items being added or removed (`quantity`) at a `locationId`.

I want to look up the stock for each item in each list at each location. Currently I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
transactions.locationId as locationId,
lists.id as listId,
lists.name AS listName,
listitems.itemId,
listitems.quantity,
items.name,
CAST(SUM(transactions.quantity) AS INT) AS currentStock,
items.warningLevel
FROM lists
LEFT JOIN listItems ON lists.id = listitems.listId
LEFT JOIN items ON items.id = listitems.itemId
LEFT JOIN transactions ON transactions.itemId = listitems.itemId
WHERE lists.organisationId = 1 AND lists.deleted = 0 AND transactions.organisationId = 1
GROUP BY transactions.locationId, lists.id, items.id;
```

Which returns:

| locationId | listId | listName | itemId | quantity | name | currentStock | warningLevel |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ECG/TPC | 1 | 5 | Tympanic Probe Covers | 10 | 5 |  |
| 1 | 1 | ECG/TPC | 5 | 2 | ECG Dots | 5 | 10 |  |
| 1 | 2 | Cannulas 20 and 22 | 6 | 4 | Cannula - 20G | 10 | 20 |  |
| 1 | 2 | Cannulas 20 and 22 | 7 | 1 | Cannula - 22G | 1 | 20 |  |
| 4 | 1 | ECG/TPC | 1 | 5 | Tympanic Probe Covers | 2 | 5 |  |
| 4 | 1 | ECG/TPC | 5 | 2 | ECG Dots | 8 | 10 |  |
| 6 | 1 | ECG/TPC | 5 | 2 | ECG Dots | 0 | 10 |  |
| 10 | 1 | ECG/TPC | 5 | 2 | ECG Dots | 5 | 10 |  |

The last two rows also need the rest of the items in the list (listId = 1), so it produces the following (emphasis mine):

| locationId | listId | listName | itemId | quantity | name | currentStock | warningLevel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ECG/TPC | 1 | 5 | Tympanic Probe Covers | 10 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | ECG/TPC | 5 | 2 | ECG Dots | 5 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | Cannulas 20 and 22 | 6 | 4 | Cannula - 20G | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | Cannulas 20 and 22 | 7 | 1 | Cannula - 22G | 1 | 20 |
| 4 | 1 | ECG/TPC | 1 | 5 | Tympanic Probe Covers | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 | ECG/TPC | 5 | 2 | ECG Dots | 8 | 10 |
| **6** | **1** | **ECG/TPC** | **1** | **5** | **Tympanic Probe Covers** | ***NULL*** | **5** |
| 6 | 1 | ECG/TPC | 5 | 2 | ECG Dots | 0 | 10 |
| 10 | 1 | ECG/TPC | 5 | 2 | ECG Dots | 5 | 10 |
| **10** | **1** | **ECG/TPC** | **5** | **2** | **ECG Dots** | ***NULL*** | **10** |

*Note*: I've put "*NULL*" in currentStock for the desired outcome to highlight that this data doesn't exist (there's no transactions for that itemId at the locationId), ideally it would just say 0 instead of *NULL*.

Currently this fails because there are no entries in `transactions` with `itemId` of 1 at `locationId` 6, or 5 at 10.

I feel like I'm close but I can't think of a way to get the result I need - any help would be really appreciated.

*P.S. I have tried searching for answers but I'm not even sure how to phrase the question, hence the terrible title*

Comment: Move `AND transactions.organisationId = 1` into the `ON` clause.

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense to use a column from a `LEFT JOIN` table in `GROUP BY`. That will group all the unmatched rows together.

Comment: Your desired result doesn't make sense. If the `transactions` row doesn't exist, how can it be in `locationId = 6`?

Comment: Because I want to know the stock (sum of transactions.quantity) for each item, in each list, at each location. The current query works, except when the current stock is null/0 because there are no transactions with that itemId and locationId there are no rows returned (which makes sense, but I want it to still have the locationId-listId-itemId row)

Comment: Join with a subquery that returns all possible locations.